# Eclipse java proposal explanation

Tags: java, eclipse

When I working with eclipse IDE I saw that in the pop-up menu that shows java proposal there is a symbol in 'S' shape a bow green dot. What does it mean ? What other symbols I can see there ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That "S" symbol is for a *static* method or variable.

If you want to learn about *static* keyword itself, you can begin by reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) and its corresponding answers.

[Here's](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_outline_view.htm) a complete description of Eclipse's icons located at *Outline View* (the view you are referring to).